# `st.audio` does not take a numpy array?

Tags: python, audio, streamlit, soundfile

The streamlit docs (https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#streamlit.audio) state that `streamlit.audio`  can take a numpy `ndarray` containing raw sample data and display an audio player. I tried this as follows on a local host:

```
import streamlit as st
import soundfile
data, sr = soundfile.read('test.wav')
st.audio(data)
```

It successfully displays an audio player and throws no errors, however there is no available sound.

Am I doing anything wrong or are the docs incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Is your code correct? It appears you unpack `data` and `sr` to variables, but then you pass `audio` to the `np.array` function. Where does `audio` come from, or should that be `data` instead?

Comment: i made a typo. Please see edit. Also I am not passing audio to np.array so I a  not sure what you are referring to there....

Comment: I'm referring to this line, `audio` is not defined in your code snippet

`st.audio(np.array([audio]))`

Comment: Oh yes, that is another typo. My bad. It should simply be `st.audio(data)`